# Localizing UIImages

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, storyboard

After reading similar questions about localization in iOS - Everybody is talking about .strings files but i have different `UIImage` with different sizes for each country and they spread all over the app.

If I'm using the old method of several storyboards the localized storyboards will not get synced with future changes on the BASE storyboard

what is the best practice for localizing UIImages?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign assets to languages.

In the project navigator, select the image file that you're loading from, and on the Utilities pane file inspector, click "Localize...".

If you are using image assets, check out this other answer:
[How to localize the images in Images.xcassets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310819/how-to-localize-the-images-in-images-xcassets)