# Xcode 8 - Localized xcassets catalog?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard, assets

I'm trying to localize some of my images in the Assets.xcassets catalog. Is there a simple way to do so? Without defining something in code in my ViewController. Just doing this by the storyboard or something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310819/how-to-localize-the-images-in-images-xcassets ?

Comment: @Larme yeah, I already read that. But is there a way to not do this in code? Considering this is a post from 2014 (and we're almost 2017), I was wondering if there was a new way with the new Xcode 8 to do this.

Comment: Can create a extension once on UIImage and keep reusing that. Interested in seeing some code?

Comment: I saw "On demand resource tags" lately, did not get a chance to try it out tough. That would probably be an option if you have heavy language dependant content.