# change pictures of ImageView by localization

Tags: arrays, swift, image, localization, imageview

Hi I have an imageView to show some Pictures. I want to show different pictures for every language. So when the Users localization is German, he gets different pictures than a User with the localization English.

This is my code. How can I make several imageArrays for every localization?

thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    mainScrollView.frame = view.frame


    imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "help0"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help1"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help3"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help4")]



    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition , y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)



        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: mainScrollView)

    }
```

Comment: Nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310819/how-to-localize-the-images-in-images-xcassets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this by using the `NSLocalizedString`, so you declare you array like this:

```
let help0 = UIImage(named: NSLocalizedString("help0", comment: ""))
let help1 = UIImage(named: NSLocalizedString("help1", comment: ""))
let help2 = UIImage(named: NSLocalizedString("help2", comment: ""))
let help3 = UIImage(named: NSLocalizedString("help3", comment: ""))
let help4 = UIImage(named: NSLocalizedString("help4", comment: ""))

let imageArray = [help0, help1, help2, help3, help4]
```

Then you add your localization langiages in your example `ENG` and `GER` and in those files you add the image you want to use, like this ([a guide](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881) of how to add localization):

```
Localization for English:
"help0" = "help0Eng";
"help1" = "help1Eng";
etc...

Localization for German:
"help0" = "help0Ger";
"help1" = "help1Ger";
etc...
```

And your `help0Eng`, `help0Ger` etc. is the name of the images in your `Assets.xcassets`. So the following will happen:

1. NSLocalizedString("help0", comment: "") will be localzied in the right file for the selected language
2. That image name will be used for help0

Answer (score 0):

[`Locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale) has what you’re looking for. During development, you can use `Locale.isoLanguageCodes` to get an array of all possible language codes (each code is a two- or three-letter string). At runtime, use `Locale.current.languageCode` to return the language code for your user’s current language.

To implement this, you could have a helper function along the lines of:

```
func localizedImageArray() -> [UIImage] {
    let currentLanguage = Locale.current.languageCode
    let imageArray: [UIImage]

    if currentLanguage == "ja" {
        [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "help0_ja"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help1_ja"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help2_ja"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help3_ja"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help4_ja")]
    } else if currentLanguage == "kr" {
        [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "help0_kr"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help1_kr"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help2_kr"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help3_kr"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help4_kr")]
    } else /* Default implementation */ {
        [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "help0"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help1"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help3"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "help4")]
    }

    return imageArray
}
```

In your `viewDidLoad()`, instead of declaring `imageArray = /* the part where you set the array with literals */`, you would declare `imageArray = localizedImageArray()`

Please note that strings should **not** be localized using this method. For localized strings, use [`NSLocalizedString`](http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/).